# Can't import module using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm trying to call a Python function in C++ using pybind11:

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    pybind11::module_ sys = pybind11::module_::import("scripts.hello_world");
    auto func = sys.attr("say_hello");
    func();

    return 0;
}
```

And I have such script in Python:

```
def say_hello():
    print("Hello from Python")
```

But when I am trying to run the main.cpp I get an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scripts'
```

So, I can't figure out why pybind can't find this module. Can somebody help?

Directories hierarchy:

```
myProject
 ∟.idea
 ∟CMakeLists.txt
 ∟src
   ∟CMakeLists.txt
   ∟main.cpp
   ∟scripts
     ∟__init__.py
     ∟hello_world.py
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't Python. You cant just place your scripts relative to one of your .cpp files inside of your project folder structure and expect that path to have any meaning.

Once your program is compiled all you have is a binary in your build directory. Where that is depends on your CMakeLists.txt. What source files your project has or what your project structure used to be is absolutely irrelevant after compilation.

In order to access files you need to either provide the **absolute path** or place your scripts folder inside of the **working directory** of your program in case you want to use relative paths. Where your working directory is depends on how your start it. But in most cases it should just be the directory which contains your executable.

Comment: so what should I do to make this code work? Pls, tell the simplest way. I tried to copy the scripts folder to the place where executable located but it doesn't work

Comment: @Dark_Phoenix Maybe try putting your hello_world.py directly inside your working directory and import `pybind11::module_::import("hello_world");`. I personally haven't worked with pybind11 but i highly doubt it resolves the whole directory with its `__init__.py` to a module and allows you to import it like you did using `"scripts.hello_world"`. At least that's not what the examples in their documentation do.